# Using Auth0 with NextJS on Heroku

Tags: heroku, next.js, auth0

I am trying to set up Auth0 to work with a NextJS app of mine on Heroku.

For that I followed the explanations given here:
https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/nextjs/interactive

I am now at this section: "Add Login to Your Application"

But problems start to appear, when I try to visit:

```
    https://myapp.herokuapp.com/api/auth/login
    Since I use "(api)" for the directory name instead of "api"; the actual URL is:
    https://myapp.herokuapp.com/auth/login
```

I see something like this:

```
    dev-g3v4xyzu75ton2c
    Oops!, something went wrong

    Callback URL mismatch.
    The provided redirect_uri is not in the list of allowed callback URLs.
    Please go to the Application Settings page and make sure you are sending
    a valid callback url from your application.

    TECHNICAL DETAILS
    See details for this error
```

And when I click "See details for this error", I get the following message:

```
    unauthorized_client: Callback URL mismatch. https://myapp.herokuapp.com/ABCD/api/auth/callback is not in the list of allowed callback URLs
```

I don't quite understand this last message but I  have checked that the URLs I set for the Allowed Callback URLs are correct.

Of course I have tried a few twicks, nonetheless without full success at this point.

I think I have configured the various parts, but obviously something is still wrong.

Any relevant tip from someone with experience using Auth0, maybe with NextJS, would be more than welcome.

Comment: I had poor experience with Auth0 libraries and spring framework. Don't know about Auth0 nextjs libraries but I'd recommend finding an openid connect/oauth2 library for nexjs and using auth0 with that.

Comment: @K.Nicholas. OK. Would you have something to recommend? When looking for a way to set up user authentication in my Heroku app, I didn't find much other than Auth0. I could also think of creating something on my own or use a combination of platforms, like going through an "auth-gate-app" on firebase which has a convenient way to handle user authentication. But I am not sure what I would come up with would be better than Auth0 which has supposedly already been used and tested by many other users.

Comment: No, I haven't spent much time looking into front end libraries. https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-auth

Comment: You may have added `https://myapp.herokuapp.com/api/auth/callback` in the callback allowed list but what is the `https://myapp.herokuapp.com/ABCD/api/auth/callback`? I mean like what is the `/ABCD/`? Did you already add that also or not?

Comment: @Kalana. No, and this is the point. The only item I have set in the Allowed Callback URLs is:
https://myapp.herokuapp.com/. Besides, https://myapp.herokuapp.com/ABCD/ is indeed an existing route in my app but I have not set it anywhere concerning Auth0, so I wonder why it is showing up in this error message.
In fact I don't know what "provided redirect_uri" is referring to.

Comment: InAuth0 callback URL list, can you add these as well -> `https://myapp.herokuapp.com/callback`, `https://myapp.herokuapp.com/api/auth/callback`, `https://myapp.herokuapp.com/ABCD/api/auth/callback`. Let me know the result

Comment: @Kalana. When I visit: https://myapp.herokuapp.com/auth/login.

I hit this:
https://myapp.herokuapp.com/ABCD/api/auth/callback?error=invalid_request&error_description=no%20connections%20enabled%20for%20the%20client&state=eyJyZXR1cm5UbyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbml2ZS00ZDNmMWQwNGUxOTAuaGVyb2t1YXBwLmNvbS9DaGFubmVsc19Qb29sIn0
(showing up in the address bar) with this display:
404
This page could not be found.

If I do this tweak of using: https://myapp.herokuapp.com/ABCD/auth/callback, I find the same problem as before (Oops!, something went wrong ....).

Comment: @Kalana. All this makes me wonder about 2 things. 1) Can it handle (api) vs api ? 2) Why is ABCD showing up ? When I think it has nothing to do with Auth0. Do you have any clue ?

Comment: @K.Nicholas. I am looking at next-auth from the link you gave me and trying to make sense of it. This is something to use along with Auth0(or something else) I suppose. Or could it be a possible replacement ?

Comment: @Michel while you have `https://myapp.herokuapp.com/ABCD/api/auth/callback` I saw an error description that says `error_description=no connections enabled for the client`. You need to define the connection first. Go to `Application -> select your app -> go to the connection tab` and enable some connections there. Then 404 will resolve

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256699/discussion-between-kalana-and-michel).

Comment: @Kalana. I am OK with that.